# Menu item callback not working

Tags: java, swing

// the following call-back works when I click on "File"

```
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    mnFile.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            btnNewButton_0.setText("File pressed");
        }
    });
    menuBar.add(mnFile);
```

// following call-back fails to respond when I click on the menu item:open

```
    mntmOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
    mntmOpen.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            btnNewButton_0.setText("Open pressed");
        }
    });
    mnFile.add(mntmOpen);
```

//Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: 1) don't add MouseLIsteners to JMenuItems but rather ActionListeners. 2) You will want to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to be able to tell what is really wrong.

Comment: As an aside, what on Earth does this have to do with your IDE?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a MouseListener!!!

If you want to do something when the `JMenu` is clicked then use a `JPopupMenuListener`:

```
JMenu file = new JMenu( "File" );

JPopupMenu popup = file.getPopupMenu();
popup.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener()
{
    public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}

    public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {}

    public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("menu clicked");
    }
});
```

Otherwise, just add an `ActionListener` to the `JMenuItem` as demonstrated in the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).